# How can I run MATLAB in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, wine, matlab

I have been using Ubuntu 16.04 for the last six months but I have not figured out how to run `MATLAB` in Ubuntu.
I tried running  `MATLAB` using `wine` but `wine` is not effective in running most apps including `MATLAB`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Linux version of Matlab, not the Windows version.  Once installed, the defaults installed, at least up until version 2016a did not create a icon with a link on the desktop or anywhere else.  Instead, you need to open a terminal window (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and run `matlab` at the prompt.  This should work.

There are ways to create an icon have it show on your HUD or side menu.  Although I have not tried this one, if you go to `Ubuntu Software Centre` you will find an entry for Matlab.  If you install that app you are supposed to get an icon installed to work with your Matlab installation.  Presumably that works but I haven't personally tried it as I created the icon and shortcut manually.

Comment: I have tried that before .. it doesn't work